# Animate background colour on exitaction

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to animate the background colour on a grid to change, once an event happens, but I can't get it working, I can get it to change colour immediately (via data triggers), but as soon as I try to introduce an animation into it, then I can't get it working (the animation doesn't seem to come into effect).

This is the current XAML I'm using (though I've tried various variations and cannot get it to animate):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Viewed}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow" />
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:02" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
<!--
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Viewed}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
</DataTrigger>
-->
```

Where Viewed is a dependency property (bool) on my Control. Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated. I've also tried setting it as an EventTrigger on a raised event which happens when the bool switches to true.

Comment: Is the Grid's `Background` actually set to a *modifiable* SolidColorBrush? Not something like `Background="Black"`.

Comment: That's one of the ways I tried too, having a static resource SolidColorBrush, and animate that, which the animation worked via an event trigger, but I couldn't get it to set the original property to LightYellow, only if the value is false

Comment: I mean if you want to animate `(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`, Grid.Background must be set to an application-defined instance of SolidColorBrush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Clemens helps, figured out what I needed to do:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridColourBrush" Color="LightYellow" />
        <Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Viewed}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GridColourBrush}" />
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:02" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <!-- snipped stuff -->
        <Grid MinWidth="525" x:Name="ContainerGrid" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}" Background="{StaticResource GridColourBrush}" />
```

So setting the background to be flat white by default, then if the DP bool is false, change the background to the static solid colour brush, which I can then animate via the exit actions.

Answer (score 0):

What i meant was simply that instead of

```
<Grid Background="LightYellow">
</Grid>
```

you would have to write

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="LightYellow" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

No need to have an extra resource.